# Getting a class to 'inform' another class that it needs to change (Events?)

Tags: c#, .net

Okay, I've been searching on the site and Google and can't quite get my head around where things need to be in terms of delegates and eventhandlers and the like so hopefully someone here can help/explain what I need to do.

So, I am writing a simple database application (using SQLite). There is a mainform that is the MDI parent (that's basically a big window with menus at the top). The menus launch other windows that allow view, edit and insert into various tables of the database.

One of those windows is a LOG window which shows my log table.

At the moment, if a user changes something in the window showing the data in TABLE. The operation also writes into the log table. If the Log window is open, however, the log view doesn't update.

So, I've figured out I probably need to 'fire' an event from my TABLE UPDATE code that my LOG window 'subscribes' to (so it can update the DataGridView).

What I can't figure out is where the different 'bits' of the event go.

Should the MdiParent have the `public delegate void EventHandler();`? If not where?

which class gets the `public static event EventHandler logGoneStale;`?

The only bit I'm reasonably sure about is that the Window that displays the log (which has a method called public void UpdateLogDataGridView() - which calls the database object/methods to (re-)populate the datagridview) needs to have:

something like `logGoneStale += new EventHandler(UpdateLogDataGridView);` in it. Is that at least right?

Totally befuddled - it seems none of the event examples/tutorials on MSDN are trying to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: Events might be the right way to go depending on the platform you're programming against. If WPF and WindowsForms, or even Silverlight, events are a good choice. If Web application, Ajax might be more adequate. So what platform?

Comment: Yes events are probably the right approach. You should also separate your architecture into layers, using Model View Controller or other approaches. The Data layer may raise the "data changed" event, the controller would be subscribed to that event and it would update the view accordingly. You shouldn't have the "window" (aka "view") attached directly to the model - that should be the job of the controller.

Comment: MVC, MVVM or similar patterns are often overkill for small applications. hunch_hunch is obviously only just learning how to use events, so I would recommend to keep it simple.

Comment: I do have three bunches of objects. There are ones that interface directly with the database. They do the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATES etc.
Then there are the main 'objects' these are what get constructed by the database code - so I have a user object that is 'filled in' during construction by the database code. These objects do all the work!
Then there's the GUI which has datagrids and buttons which do nothing more than call members of the main application objects. 
So perhaps not MVC - but certainly separation of tiers.

Comment: Then I would say your design is quite adequate for a small application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an `event` in the class that is *sending* the event, and append an event handler in the class that should *receive* the event. To make things slightly easier, starting with C# 3.5 you can forget about the `delegate` keyword altogether and use a lamba expression as event handler. Also note that it in most cases it makes no sense to make an event `static`, since usually events are fired by an *instance*, not by a *class*.

Example:

```
class SendsEvent
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void FireEvent()
    {
        if(MyEvent != null) // MyEvent is null if no handlers have been attached
        {
            MyEvent(this, new EventArgs()); // event fired here
        }
    }
}

class ReceivesEvent
{
    private SendsEvent eventSource;

    public ReceivesEvent(SendsEvent eventSource)
    {
        this.eventSource = eventSource;

        // Attach event handler - can be a lambda expression
        // or method with signature 
        // "void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)"
        this.eventSource.MyEvent += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // do something when event was fired
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Hello. Event was fired.");
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var eventSource = new SendsEvent();
        var eventReceiver = new ReceivesEvent(eventSource);
        eventSource.FireEvent(); 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I've added code similar to the SendsEvent to my dbActivityLog class such that whenever a row is updated or inserted into the table the event is fired.
However, I put the receivesEvent code into a new class that should just pop up a messagebox whenever the Event comes in. But nothing happens. Do I need to do something else on the receiving end to subscribe to the event?

Comment: Maybe you could post excerpts of you code so I can check for mistakes. The relevant parts are the definition of the event, and how you attach the event handler. Also note what I said about _static_ events.

Comment: yes, I'm not using static anymore - but that's not the problem. It's just because I was initially trying to set the delegate up in Main Program (which is static).

I'll have to do the code paste later as my code is on a different (non-internet) machine to this one that I'm posting from.

I think my problem is an instance one. I think the (new)instance of log I'm subscribing to isn't the SAME instance as the one being updated by the call from the other Window's code. Does that sound possible?

Comment: Yes, that sounds plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Working with events requires you to have both an event publisher and an event subscriber.

[**@chris'**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384719/162167) answer is correct.

Besides, you need to raise the event on the closest point where the action for which you want to be notified takes place.

For example, implementing the [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address {
        get { return address; }
        set {
            address = value;
            if (thereArePropertyChangedEventSubcribers()) 
                raisePropertyChangedEventFor("Address");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void raisePropertyChangedEventFor(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool thereArePropertyChangedEventSubcribers() { 
        return PropertyChanged != null; 
    }

    private string address;
}
```

So here, the `Customer` class allows for the publishment of its change of address. So, whenever anyone is interested to be notified when the address has changed, it subscribes to the event like so:

```
Customer.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(customerPropertyChanged);
```

Or else like so:

```
Customer.PropertyChanged += customerPropertyChanged;
```

You might even have noticed that the closest point where the address has changed in directly after it has actually changed. The only requirement is that the method used as the event handler has the same signature as the event itself. If you take a look at the [**PropertyChangedEventHandler Delegate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), one may notice that it signature awaits an `object` as the first parameter, that is, the object that fired the event, and a [**PropertyChangedEventArgs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) instance to notify about the property that has changed.

To come back to your example, you wish to be noticed whenever a log has been inserted into the underlying database so that a refresh of your Log window may occur. There are two questions that need to be answered whenever you want to use events.

- *What shall my publisher be?*
- *What shall my subscriber be?*

**What shall my publisher be?**

> **Should the MdiParent have the `public delegate void EventHandler();`?**

Short answer: No!

> **If not where?**

The event declaration best fits the publisher. Should you have a class responsible for logging, then this is where the `public delegate void EventHandler();` should reside, as it is it that is responsible to raise the event whenever there are subscribers.

Whenever there is a successful Log inserted, it shall notify whatever subscriber interested to know about the new Log Entry.

```
public class Log {
    public void UpdateLog(string description) {
        // insert the new Log line into your database.
        if (thereIsAtLeastOneNewLogEntryAddedSubscriber())
            raiseTheNewLogEntryAddedEvent();
    }

    public event EventHandler NewLogEntryAdded;

    private raiseTheNewLogEntryAddedEvent() {
        NewLogEntryAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private bool thereIsAtLeastOneNewLogEntryAddedSubscriber() {
        return NewLogEntryAdded != null;
    }
}
```

**What shall my subscriber be?**

This question can be answered through another question:

- *What do you need to do when the event fires?*

In your case, you wish to update a Log window whenever it is opened.

> **The only bit I'm reasonably sure about is that the Window that displays the log (which has a method called public void UpdateLogDataGridView() - which calls the database object/methods to (re-)populate the datagridview) needs to have:**
>
> **something like `logGoneStale += new EventHandler(UpdateLogDataGridView);` in it. Is that at least right?**

Yes, you're right! =D

You actually subscribe to the event per this line. So, it tells the application that the window that displays the log is interested to know about log changes in your database.

```
public class WindowThatDisplaysTheLog : Form {
    public WindowThatDisplaysTheLog() { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        log = new Log();
        log.NewLogEntryAdded += UpdateLogDataGridView;
    }

    private void UpdateLogDataGridView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Reload your Log entries from the underlying database.
        // You now shall see the LogDataGridView updating itself 
        // whenever a new log entry is inserted.
    }
    
    private Log log;
}
```